# Efficient way to filter and hide tr elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all `tr` elements [from the page](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/availability-in-europe/), where row doesn't contain text `720` or doesn't contain text `Country variant`

I've tried so far,

```
$("td").parent().hide().end()
.filter(function(){ return /720/.test( $(this).text() ) })
.parent().show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not directly hiding the rows ?

```
$('tr:not(:contains(720):contains("Country variant"))').hide();
```

Comment: there are two texts to test against

Comment: @mpapec then you can add another not(:contains(text")) `$('tr:not(:contains(720):not(:contains("Country variant"))').hide();`

Comment: I want something like `$('tr:not(:contains(720) and :contains(Country variant))')`

Comment: You mean you want to hide the lines which contains none of them ? Or the lines which don't contain both ?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Are you serious ? This is just a simple obvious variant of my precedent answer (not even like his one) following OP's comment...

Comment: Answers as comments are still answers... just not posted yet. Just coincidence that it is 100% the same then :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The answer is not stolen because it's like dystroy says it's a simple obvious variant to add.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie 1) my tuned answer is not even the same than his one, it's almost the same than my older one, though... 2) Please be careful with your insulting words

Answer (score 0):

In the page you just showed I tried this and works for colors and also fix the rows problem. Its almost the same as dystroy posted but style is fixed:

```
$('tr:not(:contains(720):contains("Country variant"))').remove();
$('tr:nth-child(odd)').css('background', '#f2f2f2');
```